# Glassmapper 5 SitecoreChildren listing items even if the version count is 0

Tags: sitecore-api, glass-mapper

We upgraded Glass Mapper version from `4.2.1.190` to `5.4.21.0`. 
In our model, we are using `[SitecoreChildren(InferType = true)]` to get the child items. For few of the child items, language fallback is disabled and they do not have any version in target languag say en-us. So we want to display only the items which has atleast one version. This was working fine in Glass Mapper 4 but after upgrading to Glass Mapper 5 we observed that `SitecoreChildren` is listing out the items even if the version count is `0` and language fallback is disabled.

Also, `Enforce Language Fallback` is disabled.

Models:

```
public class Product 
{
    [SitecoreField(FieldName = "Image List")]
    public virtual ImageList ImageListItem { get; set; }
}

public class ImageList 
{
    [SitecoreChildren(InferType = true)]
    public virtual IEnumerable<ImagesComponent> Images { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model ImageList
foreach(var image in model.Images)
{
  --logic --
}
```

Am I missing any setting that needs to be changes in Glass Mapper 5?

Comment: I tried enabling enforce version presence on template as mentioned in above question but no luck. Also, even if version presence is disabled, it is working as expected in glass 4 but not in glass 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Glass Mapper v5, the determination for whether an item has versions has changed from using `Sitecore.Data.Items.Item.Versions.Count` to checking if `Sitecore.Data.Items.Item[Sitecore.FieldIDs.Revision]` is null or empty. It's possible that this new method of checking the existence of the `__Revision` field is potentially inaccurate in your solution and instance of Sitecore, causing Glass to map those items without versions but still maintaining a value in the `__Revision` field.

To revert to the legacy `Sitecore.Data.Items.Item.Versions.Count` determination, you'll need to update the Glass dependency resolver to use `ItemVersionCountTask` instead of the default `ItemVersionCountByRevisionTask`. To do so, you'll need to add the following code into your `GlassMapperScCustom.cs` file in its `CreateResolver()` method:

```
public static IDependencyResolver CreateResolver(){
    var config = new Glass.Mapper.Sc.Config();

    var dependencyResolver = new DependencyResolver(config);

    // ADD THE LINE BELOW TO REPLACE THE ITEM VERSION COUNT TASK
    dependencyResolver.ObjectConstructionFactory.Replace<ItemVersionCountByRevisionTask, ItemVersionCountTask>(() => new ItemVersionCountTask());

    return dependencyResolver;
}
```

*Glass Mapper Documentation: http://www.glass.lu/mapper/documentation/Upgrade-ToV5*